# Invalid column name 'Age' in Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm running the following query in https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Users.Reputation DESC) AS [#], 
    Users.Id AS [User Link], 
    Users.Age,
    Users.Location,
    Users.Reputation,
    Users.UpVotes,
    Users.DownVotes,
    Users. CreationDate 

FROM
    Users;
```

but it returns:

> Invalid column name 'Age'.

The query is working yesterday.

Is there any database structure changes?

Comment: "The query is working yesterday." -- See also the [SEDE schema Meta.SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2678/77), last edited on Thursday, which still mentions the column.

Comment: @duplode yeah, that edit was mine. [Age is indeed gone](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/858711), and I bet it is due to GDPR as it is personal identifiable information but I'll wait  for SE Staff to confirm.

Comment: @rene I'm not sure about that, since it's information you voluntary share. Or should I say shared, because it appears you can no longer fill it in for your profile.

Comment: @Stijn yeah, it was only visible in your SE account page but it was removed this year I think.

Comment: @Stijn at least I found the Q/A about removing age from the userprofiles: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294637/where-did-the-age-go-on-the-network-profile

Comment: [*Seems* to be removed from the API too](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#pagesize=100&todate=2010-06-01&order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!T6obFFFNynRtQ3xmZm&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (although [doc says otherwise](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)), but hard to prove without a known aged user.

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm pretty sure [my age was filled before](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/578411?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow) so this confirms your finding.

Comment: Thanks, @rene.  I've filed a documentation "bug" report for that.  It looks like the end of an Age...

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Age has been removed from SEDE (and from all internal databases) as part of an audit for GDPR. We no longer display it, so there's no reason to ask for or keep it.

It was my call to remove the column completely on SEDE. I opted to do this because one of the primary usages of Age was distribution grouping there. These types of queries would silently fail if it were left in place, but always null. I'd much rather they break explicitly, so users can decide what to do, not observe bad data.

SEDE is also an intermediate step in the quarterly data dump, and we wouldn't want Age propagating to that any longer (always null, but still).

If we left it in, we'd be forever explaining why it doesn't work. I made the call to not do that and cause the break/pain now. I apologize if this adversely affects your queries, but the user data concerns must come first.

Comment: Any other missing column or Age is the only one removed?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub between the [sql-meta data](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/858711) and the [database schema documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) only `age` is now missing. I'll update the database schema documentation later today if nobody else beats me to it.

Comment: Is it possible to share what part of the GDPR made you remove it? Or is it a case of "better safe than sorry"?

Comment: It's personal data, usually linked to a specific person, which can be lead back to a natural person, which makes it fall under GDPR concerns. Hell, even a webserver session id token can fall under GDPR when you store it and can be used to track back to a user(storing login status/user id in session). It's fine to store and share such data but you have to explicitly ask people permission for both things.

Comment: @Tschallacka but it was an optional field, you filled it in when you wanted to share the data. Isn't that enough to cover "asking for permission"?

Comment: Removed from the databases, maybe, but [not from the API documentation](https://stackapps.com/questions/7914/docs-say-the-api-returns-a-users-age-but-it-doesnt-anymore).

Comment: You have to explicitly opt in, by checking a check box that it may be stored since it's not covered under the 6 legal uses to collect data. For sharing the data another checkbox and explicit opt in is required with a question like: `Do you agree that Stack Overflow may share your provided personal data with every person on the world via the various API's Stack Overflow provides?` This consent also has to be logged for as long as that data exists, to prove that consent was given. Where person can also mean legal entities of course. This consent needs also to be reversable/withdrawable.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub only Age was removed, no other changes

Comment: This is getting stupid - age is optional, one can choose to add it in because hey, we might get age related ads, the more targeted the better for me if I have to see them. Rant not aimed at SO or SOMeta by the way, just the world I guess...idiocy to me.

Comment: @Brock - it’s not being removed from the API in this major version. Doing so would break all API filters on that tree, so it will remain present and forever null there. In 3.0 (no plans for this at all), we’d cleanup and remove it.

Comment: Nick, that's good to know, but shouldn't [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user) say something like that?

Answer (score 18):

It is true, Age is gone. But not just that. We've completely dropped the Birthdate field from our database altogether (and the option is gone from the Edit Profile screen).

The API will forever return null for backwards compatibility reasons, but the Age field was dropped for SEDE exports.

Comment: yeah I noticed the birthdate field wasn't there on my profile anymore, I could've sworn it was there before and I thought I had made it up obviously I wasn't

Comment: There was a birthday field? o_O

Comment: @IvankaTodorova yes, but I never got a card so it was pointless anyway ...

Comment: @rene What do you mean by "a card"?

Comment: @IvankaTodorova a [birthday card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_card)?

Comment: @rene Ahaha, lol, neither did I. I guess Google is a better friend.