# How to see who has the most reputation for a certain age?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, age

I don't know if this is possible, but is it possible to know who has the most rep for my age? I'm really young, I want to know if anyone my age has a score higher than me.

Comment: I don't think so. I believe user age is intentionally kept private.

Comment: damn... well thanks anyways @Don'tPanic

Comment: Also, you haven't specifically said your age (and I'm not asking) but I just wanted to point this out in case you weren't aware of it: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age

Comment: @Don'tPanic wow, that's interesting, im 13 so i just made it :)

Comment: @SheshankS. Ageism just  smells!

Comment: Also, according to facts, Jon Skeet somehow has the most rep for every age.

Comment: Sorry to break it to you, but there is always somebody smarter than you of the same age at SO.  Or two or three.  Nothing wrong with being number forty-two, it is a big world out there.  You are surely number one among the people you actually know.

Comment: @HansPassant I know, again I just want to know how high I am in the SO community

Comment: @Don'tPanic Let's face it: _@JonSkeet_ has turned into an Unicorn's Rainbow Fart.

Comment: @Hans Cool encouragement!

Comment: Age used to be public through the SEDE dumps, it was changed a while back. I remember doing some analysis years ago on this stuff: 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178336/top-users-who-aged-in-teen-or-less/178337#178337

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII yes, the [age column](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/369002/578411) was [removed from the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/2678/80) after GDPR came into effect. The field It self was only shown on the network profile of the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm really young, I want to know if anyone my age has a score higher than me.

Your age doesn't matter at all (as long you're legally old enough attending here).

You can beat out *'ole chums* like me, or *kittens* you have already had for dinner.

Getting deeper into the age axis dimension won't be a useful / meaningful measure at the SE Network at all.

There are always pros and cons about *fresh views* and the *"established" state of the art*. With a *fresh view* the most important point is not to look overly naive.

Just provide **good content**, no matter what.

Comment: I know it doesn't matter, but just wanted to find out.

Comment: @SheshankS. That's typical behavior for that age ;)

Comment: Yes, yes it is :)

Comment: @SheshankS.I could tell you stories about the brick-legs, but better I don't because that would cost me comfort in controlling you :3 [Just Say No!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YR5ApYxkU-U)